# How can I convert this date format 2021-03-30T06:14:00.000Z to 2021-03-30T06:14:00+00:00 this date format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, simpledateformat, date-format

I want to convert 2021-03-30T06:14:00.000Z date format into 2021-03-30T06:14:00+00:00 date format in Javascipt.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, also there is multiple guides on how to format dates with javascript.

Comment: var result = new Date("2021-03-30T06:14:00+00:00");
result.setDate(result.getDate());
console.log(result.toISOString())

Comment: @PrakashJangir— `result.setDate(result.getDate())` is entirely redundant. Don't add information in a comment, edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

use string replace method... for example

```
let time = '2021-03-30T06:14:00.000Z';
let newTime = '2021-03-30T06:14:00.000Z'.replace('.000Z','+00:00')
```

Comment: What if we have something else instead of 000Z in date?

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex in replace method, for example:

```
let time = '2021-03-30T06:14:00.000Z'; 
let newTime = '2021-03-30T06:14:00.000Z'.replace(/(\.[0-9]*Z)$/g,'+00:00')
```

and everything that starts with . and then comes numbers and in the and it has Z will be replaced with +00:00